# opencv webcam not shutting down

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, webcam

I started the webcam using openCV but (stupidly) did not assign code for proper closing up of resources. So now the webcam is stuck. How can I restart the webcam without rebooting ?
I know rebooting will be able to release the webcam but I need a proper fix that doesn't need a reboot for every time I muck up. 
OS:ubuntu 14.04
opencv v3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unloading the kernel module

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
```

and reload again

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

This resets the cam if it is a UVC cam. For other cams it shall be similar reloading a different module. Experimenting with openCV sometimes makes the cam reinitialize using a different device (e.g. /dev/video1 instead of /dev/video0). So have a look at

```
ls /dev/video*
```

Maybe it is not locked but just on a different number.